# alpha beta pruning algorithm for position comparsion

Tags: algorithm, alpha-beta-pruning

I've developed NN model that takes two chess positions and estimates which one is better from whites' perspective acording to that article: https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~wolf/papers/deepchess.pdf
Author writes about alpha beta pruning algorithm but he wrote very little and I can't conclude what author meant. I've tried to search in the internet but I didn't find that algorithm. Is this algorithm available anywhere? Pseudo code would be enough.

Comment: [Alpha-Beta on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning)

Comment: this algorithm doesn't include postion comparsion

Comment: Position comparison is a completely different task. Basically it subsumes  chess knowledge and heuristics. Alpha-Beta is a generic optimization technique to speed up searching for optimal values in game trees.

Comment: I know how classic alpha-beta works, but author of this article uses some modification of alpha-beta algorithm which I want to find. Heuristics will be used later by myself.